# Beamer: hyperlink to bottom of slide with stepwise overlay-specification

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I am making a presentation where I move from one frame to another through a hyperlink to a hypertarget and then back to a hypertarget at the last position in the first frame. This works fine, but when I use `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` in order to get stepwise uncovering of bullet points, the link always moves the presentation back to the beginning of the first frame. What I would like, however, is that the second hyperlink moves to the bullet point where I set the hypertarget.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} %stepwise uncovering
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
        \item \hyperlink{target1}{\beamergotobutton{Go to target 1}}
        \item \hypertarget{target2}{C}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \hypertarget{target1}{Target 1}
        \item \hyperlink{target2}{\beamergotobutton{Go back to first slide next bullet point}}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Hello Martin, thanks for the welcome and the suggested edits!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of `\only<4>{target content}` seems to achieve your goal.

Note: `visible` and `onslide` won't work, but `onslide*` would work since it maps to `\only` while onslide+ also maps to `visible`, therefore, won't work either.

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} %stepwise uncovering
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item <1-3> A
        \item <2-3> B
        \item <3-3>\hyperlink{target1}{\beamergotobutton{Go to target 1}}
        \only<4>{\item \hypertarget{target2}{C}}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \hypertarget{target1}{Target 1}
        \item \hyperlink{target2}{\beamergotobutton{Go back to first slide next bullet point}}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jesse, this was what I was looking for! One slight modification on your code: I would still like to display the previous items after going back through the hyperlink, so I changed the options for the first three items from `<i-3>` to `<i-4>`.

Comment: Yes, that is the right way to do. Since your OP wants to back to where the second target is, so I did that.